AddUpdate page for class with multiple child classes using EF Core
Within my Blazor Web App .net 8 project I use Entity Framework Core. Below are a few classes I use in my project with all the necessary properties. I am trying for days to create a Razor page with an EditForm where I can create / update an Activity with all the child elements. But I did not manage to create a 100% working script. I got tracking errors, inserting Identity not allowed errors, etc ...
How to create a Razor page with .cs script to Add/Update an Activity and save all child entities? What is the correct way to collect existing items that can be added to the Activity. And what is the correct way to Add/Update this Activity?
Last script lines I tried:
Context = _dbContext.CreateDbContext();

// I use this to collect existing items:
// I also tried with .AsNoTracking()
List<SalesItem> _salesItems = await Context.SalesItems.Where(x => x.Deleted == false).ToListAsync();
List<Volunteer> _volunteers= await Context.Volunteers.Where(x => x.Deleted == false).ToListAsync();

// I use this to add a new Activity:
Context.Add(_activity);

Activity.cs
public class Activity
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<VolunteerNecessity> VolunteerNecessities { get; set; }
  public List<SalesItemNecessity> SalesItemNecessities { get; set; }
}

VolunteerNecessity.cs
public class VolunteerNecessity
{
  public Volunteer Volunteer { get; set; }
  public int VolunteerId { get; set; }
  public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
  public VolunteerActivity VolunteerActivity { get; set; }
  public int VolunteerActivityId { get; set; }
}

SalesItemNecessity.cs
public class SalesItemNecessity
{
  public SalesItem SalesItem { get; set; }
  public int SalesItemId { get; set; }
  public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
  public int Amount { get; set; }
}

Volunteer.cs
public class Volunteer
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

VolunteerActivity.cs
public class VolunteerActivity
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

SalesItem.cs
public class SalesItem
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}


Read up about Aggregates - search "aggregate root".  They provide a pattern for managing complex objects.

According to your description, I suggest you could write a repository to help you add and update the entity instead of directly using the context.add method which will cause a lot of issue.
More details, you could refer to below codes:
For example, you have two data model inside the dbcontext:
public class SalesItemNecessity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    // public int SalesItemId { get; set; }
    public string? AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}

public class VolunteerNecessity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? VolunteerName { get; set; }
    // public int VolunteerId { get; set; }
    public string? AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
    public string? VolunteerActivityName { get; set; }
    // public int VolunteerActivityId { get; set; }
}

Activity is the view model which we will not directly use it for the dbcontext.
public class Activity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<VolunteerNecessity> VolunteerNecessities { get; set; }
    public List<SalesItemNecessity> SalesItemNecessities { get; set; }
}

repository class:
public class ActivityRepository
{
    private readonly ActivityDbContext _context;

    public ActivityRepository(ActivityDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(Activity activity)
    { 
        _context.VolunteerNecessities.AddRange(activity.VolunteerNecessities);
        _context.SalesItemNecessities.AddRange(activity.SalesItemNecessities);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync(Activity activity)
    { 
        _context.VolunteerNecessities.UpdateRange(activity.VolunteerNecessities); 
        _context.SalesItemNecessities.UpdateRange(activity.SalesItemNecessities); 
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

Then you could register this repository in program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped<ActivityRepository>();
Then inside the blazor you could inject and use it like below：
// inject the  activityRepository
@inject BlazorApp2.Repositories.ActivityRepository activityRepository

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SaveActivity">Add</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="EditActivity">Edit</button>

@code {
private async Task SaveActivity()
{
    //...
    await activityRepository.AddAsync(activity);
    //...
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Home");
}

private async Task EditActivity()
{
    //...
    await activityRepository.UpdateAsync(activity);
    //...
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Home");
}
}

Result:


